# What is the smallest monetary unit in Tezos?

Tags: protocol

What is the smallest monetary unit in Tezos, and where is it defined in the code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently 1 tez (1 XTZ) is divisible to six decimal places, and the smallest unit is called a *micro tez (mutez)*.

1 tez = 1,000,000 micro tez

In code it is referred to as `one_mutez` and it is defined in [src/proto_013_PtJakart/lib_protocol/tez_repr.ml](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/src/proto_013_PtJakart/lib_protocol/tez_repr.ml#L49):

```
(* all other constant are defined from the value of one micro tez *)
let one_mutez = Tez_tag 1L

let max_mutez = Tez_tag Int64.max_int

let mul_int (Tez_tag tez) i = Tez_tag (Int64.mul tez i)

let one_cent = mul_int one_mutez 10_000L

let fifty_cents = mul_int one_cent 50L

(* 1 tez = 100 cents = 1_000_000 mutez *)
let one = mul_int one_cent 100L
```

Comment: The Tezos shell also makes use of "nanotez" in fine-grained calculations for fees, where 1000 nanotez = 1 mutez.  I believe such values are rounded (truncated?) to mutez before being passed to the protocol proper and stored in the persistent chain data.